# How to run a console application created by Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

This is probably going to be really simple but;

I've created my first C++ program in Code::Blocks, and I used the standard Hello World that the IDE gave me. It builds and runs within the IDE perfectly. It also created an executable file in the Debug/Release directory.

How do I run that file? It ignores double click in a folder and typed HelloWorld in a terminal.

Using Code::Blocks 10.05 and Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Comment: `/path/to/executable_file`

Comment: ./HelloWorld in the folder containing the executable.

Comment: Thanks drescherjm. I was playing around with shells, xterms, digging through online forums. Completely forgot it was Linux and I needed ./

Comment: Double clicking is not ignored, but I suspect that the hello world program close immediately.

Comment: @H2CO3, I should have thanked Carbonic acid as well, sorry about that. Jarod42 double clicking doesn't work even when I put a cin.get() into the code to force it not to close until I'm ready. Never mind, maybe it will when I start using wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a shell and type the relative or absolute path to your executable.

You can probably also drag and drop the file in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Linux doesn't recognize .exe as an executable file, you can use g++ to build your .cc/.cpp file using g++ filename.cc. After that, it should be an executable file and you should be able to run it in terminal using ./filename, however if it doesn't work, you can use

```
sudo chmod a+x filename
```

and that should add the executable permission to everybody.